# Bounded covariant derivative of curvature tensor

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-functions

Let $M$ be a complete Riemannian manifold.
Suppose that there are positive constants $i_0$ and $K$ such that the injectivity radius of $M$ is at least $i_0$ and $|\mathrm{Rm}|\le K$ and $|\nabla  \mathrm{Rm}|\le K$ at all points.
(Here $\mathrm{Rm}$ is the Riemannian curvature tensor and $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection on $M$.)

I suspect that the following statement is known:

> For any $\alpha\in (0,1)$, any $\tfrac{i_0}2$-ball can be covered by a coordinate chart such that in these coordinates $\|g_{ij}\|_{2,\alpha}$ and $\|g^{ij}\|_{2,\alpha}$ are uniformly bounded (with constant depending on $\alpha$, $i_0$, $K$, and $\dim M$).

Do you know of a reference to this statement or a theorem that implies it?

**Remarks**

- Harmonic coordinates should work and the argument should be close to the proof of Shefel--Sabitov + DeTurck--Kazdan.
- Thomas Schick proved a [weaker statement](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9810107.pdf).

Comment: What is the norm that you mean precisely?

Comment: Yes, this is known. Greene-Wu and Stefan Peters proved that with the bound on sectional curvature, harmonic coordinates exist on the geodesic ball and the metric is $C^{1,\alpha}$. The $C^{2,\alpha}$ bound then follows by a standard elliptic estimate.

Comment: Anderson-Cheeger have a nice proof using a blowup argument.

Comment: @DeaneYang Could you make an answer from your comments? (So, the question would be "answered".)

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I mean the $C^{2,\alpha}$-norm.

Comment: Let me check the references before I make this an official answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did not find any reference the proves a theorem as strong as stated in the question.

Greene-Wu and Stefan Peters indepdently proved the following using almost linear coordinates (defined and studied by Jost and Karcher) and harmonic coordinates (first studied by DeTurck and Kazdan):

Given a Riemannian mnanifold $M$, constants $i_0, K, a > 0$ and $0 <\alpha < 1$, the following holds: If $|\mathrm{Rm}|<K$, and the injectivity radius at $p \in M$ is greater than $i_0$, There exists $\rho(i_0,K,\dim M, a, \alpha) > 0$ and $\mu(i_0,K,\dim M, a, \alpha)$ such that there exist harmonic coordinates on the geodesic ball of radius $\rho$, where the metric tensor, written with respect to the coordinates, satisfy $a^{-1} < g < a$ and $|g|_{C^{1,\alpha}} < \mu$.

If in addition, there is a bound $|\nabla\operatorname{Rm}| < K'$, then, using standard Schauder estimates for elliptic PDEs, there is a corresponding bound on the $C^{2,\alpha}$ norm of $g$.

The construction of the harmonic coordinates, via almost linear coordinates, is explained in detail in a monograph by Jost on harmonic maps.

I and Anderson-Cheeger proved a similar result assuming only a pointwise bound on Ricci curvature and an $L^{(\dim M)/2}$ bound on sectional curvature. Anderson and Cheeger's proof is a nice one using a blowup argument.

I do not know if this is good enough for you. Let me know if you want the precise references.

More about Schauder estimates: The best reference for this is the book by Gilbarg and Trudinger. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_estimates#Interior_estimates) provides a nice summary. For harmonic coordinates, it goes something like this:

In harmonic coordinates,
$$ g^{ij}\Gamma^k_{ij} = 0. $$
From the theorems of Green-Wu and Peters, $g$ satisfies the pointwise bound
$$ a^{-1}\delta \le g \le a\delta,
$$
and is $C^1$.
A straightforward calculation shows that this implies that the Ricci curvature satisfies
$$
g^{ij}\partial^2_{ij}g_{kl} = R_{kl} + Q(\partial g,\partial g).
$$
The right side satisfies a $C^0$ bound, which, using Schauder estimates, imply a $C^{1,\alpha}$ bound on $g$. If, in addition, there is a $C^0$ bound on $\nabla R$, then the right side has a $C^{0,\alpha}$ bound. Schauder estimates then imply a $C^{2,\alpha}$ bound on $g$.

Comment: Could you say bit more about "standard Schauder estimates for elliptic PDEs", maybe a reference or a close example with this argument?

Comment: @AntonPetrunin, I've added a sketch of how to prove regularity.